# Возможно ли привязать KeyListener к клавиатуре?

Tags: java

Я хотел бы спросить можно ли привязать KeyListener  к клавиатуре, то есть можно ли сделать так чтобы при запуске программы она не открывала окно, где и будет KeyListener любого вида привязанный к JTextField например, а сразу читала клавиатуру, и например при нажатии Enter закрывалась?

Comment: Глобальные хуки на яве? JNI и c++ попахивает...

Comment: С JTextField это был пример к чему можно привязать, но как привязать к самой клаве

Comment: Думаете на С++ лучше выйдет?

Comment: Повторяю, читайте JNI. То что вы хотите делать - это хук сигналов ОС. Ява кроссплатформеная, а вы тут хотите native код дёргать.

Comment: @George, >>Думаете на С++ лучше выйдет?<< Кто куда выйдет? Я говорю пишите библиотеку на плюсах, публикуйте методы от WinApi (или линуховые аналоги) и через вашу яву дёргайте native код из вашей библиотеки.

Comment: Вот пример глобальных хуков: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook Вы же понимаете, что то что вы хотите сделать - считается низкоуровневым решением, и для явы, не совсем тривиальная задача?

Comment: Ну а что по вашему является высокоуровневым решением?

Comment: Напишите свою ОС на яве, дёргаете хуки через неё. Вот вам высокоуровневое решение.